# Consulta en cuatro columnas de una misma tabla mysql, un valor que viene de un SELECT OPTION

Tags: php, mysql, select

tengo una Tabla con las siguientes columnas (Date, Evento , nivel1, nivel2, nivel3, nivel4)

necesito seleccionar de 3 combos(DATE, EVENTO Y NIVEL), y necesito que me busque el valor de Nivel y que este en alguna de las 4 columnas(nivel1, nivel2, nivel3 , nive 4)

```
SELECT * FROM ceremonia WHERE date = '2021-04-08' AND event_id = '39'
(AND nivel1 = '4' OR nivel2 = '4' OR nivel3 = '4' OR nivel4 = '4') ORDER BY 
date DESC
```

Comment: El último `AND` lo tienes que poner fuera del paréntesis `...AND (nivel1...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Como Pablo bien plantea, se requiere alguna explicación. Gracias por señalarlo)

Puesto que usando las columnas *date* y *event_id* puedes ubicar el registro que necesitas, solamente faltaría determinar  si alguna de tus columnas *nivel1...4* cumple con la condición requerida (en el ejemplo sería que una de ellas contenga el valor '4'):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ceremonia 
WHERE 
    date = '2021-04-08' AND 
    event_id = '39' AND 
    (nivel1 = '4' OR nivel2 = '4' OR nivel3 = '4' OR nivel4 = '4') 
 ORDER BY date DESC
```

Las condiciones significan: que la fecha sea '2021-04-08' (podría ser otra según lo requiera tu código) **Y** que el id del evento sea 39 (lo mismo, puede variar segú tu código) **Y** que alguna de las columnas nivel1...4  (usamos paréntesis y el operador *OR*, lo cual significaría "cualquiera de ellas") contenga el valor '4'

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación a tus respuestas. Pegar un código solamente no es una respuesta de calidad. Puede resultar obvio para ti pero tal vez no sea tan obvio para otras personas